# Node Streams - Listening for unpipe in a Readable Stream

Tags: node.js, fs, node-streams

So, I've created a read stream that first connects to an SFTP and starts reading from a file. At any point, my code can unpipe that readstream and do something else. For example, I might use this to get the first few rows of a CSV and stop reading.

The problem is, I don't know how to listen for the `unpipe` event in my readStream constructor so that I can correctly close the SFTP connection. I use a `flush` method in write streams, is there something like that for read streams?

Here's a simplified portion of my readStream constructor:

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client,
      nom = require('noms');

function getStream (get) {
    const self = this;
    const conn = new Client();

    let client,
        fileData,
        buffer,
        totalBytes = 0,
        bytesRead = 0;

    let read = function(size,next) {
        const read = this;
        // Read each chunk of the file
        client.read(fileData, buffer, bytesRead, size, bytesRead,
            function (err, byteCount, buff, pos) {
                bytesRead += byteCount;
                read.push(buff);
                next();
            }
        );
    };

    let before = function(start) {
        // setup the connection BEFORE we start _read
        conn.on('ready', function(){
            conn.sftp(function(err,sftp) {
                sftp.open(get, 'r', function(err, fd){
                    sftp.fstat(fd, function(err, stats) {
                        client = sftp;
                        fileData = fd;
                        totalBytes = stats.size;
                        buffer = new Buffer(totalBytes);

                        start();
                    });
                });
            });
        }).connect(credentials);
    };

    return nom(read,before);
}
```

Later I might call `myStream.pipe(writeStream)` and then `myStream.unpipe()`. But because I have no way of listening for that `unpipe`event, the reading stops, but the SFTP connection stays open and eventually times out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after doing more research, I learned that ReadStreams are not passed the `unpipe` event when you call `readStream.unpipe(writeStream)`. That event is passed to just the writeStream. In order to listen for the unpipe, you need to explicitly emit an event on the readStream, like so:

```
readStream.emit('unpipe');
```

You can listen for this event anywhere, inside or outside your stream constructor, which is really convenient. So, that would make the code above look like this:

```
function getStream (get) {
    /**
     * ... stuff
     * ... read()
     * ... before()
     * ... etc
     */

    let readStream = nom(read,before);

    readStream.on('unpipe', function(){
        console.log('called unpipe on read stream');
    });

    return readStream;
}
```

Moral of the story, streams already have the [Event Emitter class methods](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events), so you can emit and listen for custom events out of the box.